# How to open a popup form from a view link?

Tags: views, 8

I'm really struggling with this issue.
Well I'm having a view, in this view a field configured as personalized text as a link.
I want to open a popup form on click on the link.
Here is what I did in the method called by the link:

```
 $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $title = 'Title for the Popup.';
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
  $response->setAttachments($form['#attached']);
  $content = '<div class="test-popup-content">' . 'Content in HTML format' . '</div>';
  $options = array(
    'dialogClass' => 'popup-dialog-class',
    'width' => '75%',
  );
  $modal = new OpenModalDialogCommand($title, $content, $options);
  $response->addCommand($modal);
  return $response;
```

But It's not working at all!
Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is building an ajax response. This only works in ajax callbacks, nowhere else.

If you want to make a link modal, so that it will open in a popup, you have to set the class `use-ajax` and the attribute `data-dialog-type`. Like in this example from ConfigSync.php:

```
$links['view_diff'] = [
  'title' => $this->t('View differences'),
  'url' => Url::fromRoute($route_name, $route_options),
  'attributes' => [
    'class' => ['use-ajax'],
    'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
    'data-dialog-options' => json_encode([
      'width' => 700,
    ]),
  ],
];
```

For modal links to work you need to attach a library, see [How to create modal windows (pop-ups)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229196/how-to-create-modal-windows-pop-ups)

Comment: thank you for the  answer, but where can I can configure the class and the attribute from a link view?

Comment: The simplest method would be to rewrite the field with the link markup including the class and attribute.

Comment: <a class='use-ajax' data-dialog-type='modal' data-accepts="application/vnd.drupal-dialog" data-dialog-options="{"width":500}" href='url> modal </a>   but still don't work :(

Comment: This works: `<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" href="http://mysite/node/1">Modal link</a>`